# How to navigate to next page taking params from current page and persist it even after browser refresh in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have to navigate to next page on click of a link with parameters from current page and also want to persist that param if browser refresh in reactjs

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please see [ask] and [mcve] The answer is you can use something like local storage in the browser...

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is the answer.
before sending the client to the link, transform the data to a json string, then save it on local storage, th
en redirect the client, then get the previous data and parse it.

```
const data = your-data
const stringData = JSON.stringify(data)
localStorage.set("prevdata", stringData)
```

Redirect the client, and then

```
const prevData = JSON.parse(localStorage.get("prevdata"))
```

Comment: An alternative is using redux persist, but it is overkill